# Blazor Server app with Microsoft Entra ID authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server app registered in Microsoft Entra ID and I want to get the logged in user data and some other users data, too.
I registered this app in this way:

- Add permissions to another API : API URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All
- Sopes defined by the API: User.Read.All

How can I get these user information (name, uid, email address, etc.) from Azure, please?
This solution works for me, but I would like to use it as a service per request in Program.cs:

```
[CascadingParameter]
private Task<AuthenticationState>? authenticationState { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    if (authenticationState is not null)
    {
        var authState = await authenticationState;
        var user = authState?.User;

        if (user?.Identity is not null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            authMessage = $"{user.Identity.Name} is authenticated.";
            var claims = user.Claims;

            //These are just examples
            var uid = claims.Where(x => x.Type.Equals("uid")).FirstOrDefault().Value;
            var name = claims.Where(x => x.Type.Equals("name")).FirstOrDefault().Value;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I tried this but it gives me an error:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'User' on type 'BlazorServerAppAzureAD.Pages.Index'. There is no registered service of type 'BlazorServerAppAzureAD.Data.IUser'.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUser, User>(st =>
{
    var authState = st.GetService<AuthenticationState>();
    var user = authState?.User;
    if (user?.Identity is not null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var claims = user.Claims;

        var uid = claims.Where(x => x.Type.Equals("uid")).FirstOrDefault().Value;
        var name = claims.Where(x => x.Type.Equals("name")).FirstOrDefault().Value;
        var email = claims.Where(x => x.Type.Equals("preferred_username")).FirstOrDefault().Value; 
        return new User { Id = new Guid(uid), Name = name, UserName = user.Identity.Name, Email = email };
    }
    return null;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use middleware to get user info like below.

**Why**

`builder.Services.xxx` is used to register the service. The code after `var app = builder. Build();` are middlewares, and each HTTP request come in, it is executed sequentially.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var user = context.User; 

    if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        //var uid = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.Equals("uid"))?.Value;
        var name = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.Equals("name"))?.Value;
        var email = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.Equals("preferred_username"))?.Value;
        //context.Response.Headers.Add("X-User-UID", new Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues(uid));
    }

    await next();
});
```

[image]